# Slowly diverging infinite integer strictly convex set

Tags: number-theory, discrete-mathematics

The infinite set of points $(n, n^2)$ for $n\ge1$ is strictly convex. We define the "rate of divergence" measure as the sum of $log_2$ of both components. So for this example the $n$th point in the set takes $3log_2n$ "bits of memory" to store.

It can be slightly improved by considering the infinite set $\left(n, \frac{n(n+1)}{2}\right)$ but it only saves a small additive constant for each additional point. This is the best we can do for consecutive $x$ values.

I wonder if by relaxing this constraint (spacing $x$ values farther apart) we can achieve multiplicative constant better (smaller) than $3$, keeping the "strictly convex" constraint in mind. Farey sequence & Stern–Brocot tree come to mind...

Answer (score 0):

If
$f''(x) > 0$
then
$(n, f(n))$
is convex.

For example,
if $f(x) = x^2$,
then
$f''(x) = 2 > 0$,
so this works.

Let's try
$f(x) = x^{1+c}$.
Then
$f'(x) = (1+c) x^c$
and
$f''(x)
=x(1+c)x^{c-1}
\gt 0$
so this works for
any $c > 0$.

Try a slower growing one:
$f(x) = x\ln(x)
$.
$f'(x) = 1+\ln(x),
f''(x) = \frac1{x}
\gt 0
$,
so this also works.

See if you can do better.

Comment: I should have made it clear that the points must lie on the integer grid.